# Silerverlight dragdrop problem

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Hi am using silverlight 3 with VS 2010. I am using controlsToolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget along with drag and drop functionality. I found that Oct 09 release of silverlight toolkit added drag drop feature. but i could not download the same form anywhere. i downloaded the latest tool kit from http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528 but when i try to add following property

```
mswindows:DragDrop.AllowDrop="True"
```

it says AllowDrop not found in type DragDorp.

Anyone encountered the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the later version it is just AllowDrop not mswindows:DrapDrod.AllowDrop

Answer (score 0):

Now i copied the controls toolkit released in 2009 November from another machine and using it. It works fine with that version.. ! No idea whether it is removed in later version.